# sparklyr::spark_read_csv java.net.URISyntaxException on windows

Tags: sparklyr

I'm running RStudio on Windows and successfully connects to Azure Databricks using databricks-connect.
On Databricks I have mounted an Azure Datalake Gen2 filesystem on /mnt/clientdata.
In Python, on Windows machine, I can successfully run

```
df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load("dbfs:/mnt/clientdata/rawdata/instrumentstatic/instrumentstatic-asisa/v2.6/coronation/2020/05/12/114543/InstrumentStaticData_JPM_20200511_20200512132625.csv.gz")
```

If I run the same scenario, with the same path, but with sparklyr::spark_read_csv, I get an

```
Error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: C:%5Cmnt%5Cclientdata%5Crawdata%5Cinstrumentstatic%5Cinstrumentstatic-asisa%5Cv2.6%5Ccoronation%5C2020%5C05%5C12%5C114543%5CInstrumentStaticData_JPM_20200511_20200512132625.csv.gz
```

**sparklyr::spark_read_csv** calls **spark_normalize_path**, which calls R base function **normalizePath**. This function appends either C:\ or C:\currentdirpath, depending if I specify dbfs: in my path or not.
If I remove the call to **normalizePath** in **sparklyr**, my code works perfectly.

How can I get around this behavior when running sparklyr on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

reference paths with three forward slashes: `dbfs:///mnt/clientdata/...`